# Increasing parameter $\omega$ in $x[n] = e^{j\omega n }$

Tags: discrete-signals, frequency

Suppose $x[n] = e^{j\omega n }$. I've seen following statement many times in the different sources:

> For the discrete-time sinusoidal signal $x[n]$, as $\omega$ increases from $\omega = 0$ toward $\omega = \pi$, $x[n]$ oscillates progressively more rapidly. However, as $\omega$ increases from $\omega = \pi$ to $\omega = 2\pi$, the oscillations become slower.

I think it means that if we increase $\omega = 0$ toward $\omega = \pi$, fundumental frequency of $x[n]$ should increase. If we set $\omega = \frac{\pi}{3}$ then $$\frac{\omega}{2\pi} = \frac{\pi /3 }{2\pi} = \frac{1}{6} = \frac{m}{N} \implies f_0 = \frac{w}{m} = \frac{\pi}{3}$$
and if $\omega = \frac{5\pi}{13}$ then $$\frac{\omega}{2\pi} = \frac{5\pi /13 }{2\pi} = \frac{5}{26} = \frac{m}{N} \implies f_0 = \frac{w}{m} =\frac{\pi}{13}$$
So we have increased $\omega$ but the fundamental frequency has been decreased.

So what's wrong here? Is my understanding about the aforementioned statement wrong? If so, what happens exactly to the fundamental frequency as we change $\omega$?

Comment: Something you might be missing: when $\omega$ is defined from 0 to $2\pi$ (or $-\pi$ to $pi$), it usually means that its units are radians/sample, not the usual radians/second.

Comment: @MBaz Would you elaborate, please?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalized_frequency_(unit)

Comment: @MBaz Okay, so here the unit of $\omega$ is radians/sample but what is wrong, then?

Comment: What is happening is aliasing. As the frequency (in radians/sample) increases beyond $\pi$, what you get is a lower-frequency alias. Discrete signals can only have frequencies in the range $-\pi,\pi$ rads/sample.

Comment: @MBaz But here the frequency doesn't go beyond $\pi$.

Comment: I must be missing something -- "as  $\omega$ increases from $\pi$  to $2\pi$ , the oscillations become slower" ??

Comment: Just in case it's not clear, you can't convert from rads/sample to Hz in the way you did, you must involve the sampling frequency in your calculations.

Comment: @MBaz No, my question isn't about that. I said that if we increase $\omega$ from $0$ to $\pi$ the fundamental frequency should increase also but if we set $\omega = \frac{\pi}{3}$ then $f_0 = \frac{\pi}{3}$ and if $\omega = \frac{5\pi}{13}$ then $f_0 = \frac{\pi}{13}$. So here we have increased $\omega$ but fundamental frequency has been decreased.

Comment: I'll insist: $\omega=\pi/3$ (rad/s) does not mean that $f_0=\pi/3$ (Hz). And, if $\omega>\pi$, the signal becomes aliased and its actual frequency is less than $\pi$.

Comment: If I'm still missing something, then I'd ask you to (1) make all units explicit in your question (2) explain how you are calculating $f_0$ given $\omega$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have assumed that if a discrete sinusoidal is of higher frequency then its fundamental frequency should also be higher. This is not correct assumption.

Secondly, you are mixing this understanding of yours with rapidness of oscillations of a discrete sinusoidal.

1. Even if fundamental frequency of $2^{nd}$ sinusoidal is $\frac{2\pi}{26}$, the $2^{nd}$ discrete sinusoidal is the $5^{th}$ harmonic of it's fundamental frequency. Whereas, $1^{st}$ discrete sinusoidal of discrete frequency $\frac{\pi}{3}$ is the very $1^{st}$ harmonic of it's fundamental frequency $\frac{\pi}{3}$. So, comparison between fundamental frequency cannot give you a sense of rapidness of oscillation of digital frequencies.
2. Then what can give you the sense of rapidness: the digital frequencies themselves.

$e^{j\frac{5\pi}{13}n}$ will oscillate more rapidly than $e^{j\frac{\pi}{3}n}$ because at every change of $n$, the change in its phase is more i.e. $\frac{5\pi}{13} > \frac{\pi}{3}$. This will happen until $\omega = \pi$.

What happens when $\omega > \pi$, for example $\omega = 2\pi$.

When $\omega = 2\pi$, even then the change in phase at every change of $n$ is more than a sinusoid with $\omega = \pi/3$. Ofcourse, at every step the former changes its phase by $2\pi$ and the later only changes its phase by $\frac{\pi}{3}$. But when the change in phase is $2\pi$ at every step, it will seem like the phase is not changing at all. Changing phase by $2\pi$ is same as not changing it at all.

In general, changing a phase by $\omega = \pi + \omega_o$ is same as changing it by $-(\pi-\omega_o)$, where $\omega_o \le \pi$. That is why the rapidness of oscillation increases only till $\omega$ reaches $\pi$, and it starts decreasing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You said that "I think you have assumed that if a discrete sinusoidal is of higher frequency then its fundamental frequency should also be higher. This is not correct assumption". Would you explain please why this is a wrong assumption? What's the exact definition of the frequency and fundamental frequency, then?

Comment: The assumption is wrong because of what you are observing , the sinusoid with higher frequency is having lower fundamental frequency in the example you have taken. And, there is nothing wrong in that. It is correct, a sinusoid with higher frequency can have lower fundamental frequency. Greatness of a frequency is because of the value of the frequency and not because of its fundamental frequency.

Comment: Could you give a mathematical definition for them, please?

Comment: Definition of fundamental frequency of a discrete sinusoid is reciprocal of its period scaled by $2\pi$.

Comment: And what about the frequency of a discrete sinusoid?

Comment: Definition of frequency of a discrete sinusoid is rate of change of its phase.

Comment: That is why you should compare frequency for comparing rapidness of oscillation. Fundamental frequency is just related to its period and cannot tell you anything about the rapidness of oscillation of the original discrete frequency. The original discrete frequency can be some higher harmonic of its fundamental frequency, which will be oscillating at much higher rate than the fundamental frequency.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't seen this before. Please provide a reliable source for this definition.

Comment: Check page:5 of the pdf from Portland State University for definition of Fundamental frequency: http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~fli/418/Notes_Chapter_7.pdf  . Also, google definition of frequency of a sinusoid you will get tons of reliable sources for that. For both continuous and discrete time. The definition remains same.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what happens as we start increasing the frequency of this complex exponential from $w =0$ to $w=\pi$. At precisely $w=0$, we have the sequence $x[n] = 1$ for all n. Clearly there is no oscillation at this frequency. Now consider $w = \pi$, the sequence is $x[n] = e^{j\pi n}$, but this is simply $x[n] = (-1)^n$ , clearly this signal changes polarity every sample and hence exhibits maximum oscillation (rate of change), as we move up in frqeuency above this it is trivial to see that with increasing frequency till $2\pi$, the fluctuations in the signal will only decrease. Hence $w = \pi$ is the highest frequency of oscillations

Comment: I see but what about that example? Why it doesn't follow this rule?

Comment: Is $f_0$ is continuous time frequency? Could you define $f_0$, then I can better explain with reference to your example

Comment: It is fundamental frequency of signal $x[n]$.

Comment: Fundamental frequency is given by the periodicity of the signal. It is fixed for a signal, could you explain what do you mean by $w = \frac{\pi}{3}$ corresponding to $f_0 = \frac{\pi}{3}$, if $f_0$ corresponds to analog frqeuency then it is 1/6 for $w = \frac{\pi}{3}$

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: I am not sure how you concluded that in second case the fundamental freuency is $\frac{\pi}{13}$, fundamental frqeuency is defined by period N of the signal $x[N]$ , here have a look at this link, it's s not derived simply removing the coefficient of the numerator. http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e59/lectures/Fundamental_Frequency/node2.html

Comment: Fundamental frqeuency is $2\frac{\pi}{N}$ where $N$ is the basic period of the signal.

Comment: We have $\frac{\omega}{2\pi} = \frac{5\pi /13 }{2\pi} = \frac{5}{26} = \frac{m}{N}$. So $f_0 = \frac{\omega}{m} = \frac{\pi}{13}$.

Comment: When $w = \frac{\pi}{3}$, then N = 6, and when $w = \frac{\pi}{13}$ then period is 26, clearly the first signal is periodic with a shorter period meaning higher fundamental frqeuency than the second signal. The signal $e^{jwn}$ is a signal in which you would either substitute $w = \frac{5\pi}{13} $ or $w = \frac{\pi}{13}$ at one time..The $w$ you put here itslef defines that this $w$ is the fundamental frqeuency. That's your confusion I think

Comment: hay @Dspguysam since you're using $\LaTeX$, you should know that "$w$" is not the same as "$\omega$".

Comment: @robert, yes, wrote that in a hurry